# Cannot call fadeOut more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

I am running this code when the user clicks on a button in a table row to remove it:

```
var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
  $killrow.addClass("success");
  $killrow.fadeOut(200, function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

This can be called multiple times resulting in multiple rows deleted. Though when I use this code block later in the code as well, it doesn't work. E.g.

```
if (something) {
  var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
  $killrow.addClass("success");
  $killrow.fadeOut(200, function() { //this is called
    $(this).remove();
  });
} else {
  if (something else) {
    var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
    $killrow.addClass("success");
    $killrow.fadeOut(200, function() { //this is never called. The two lines before this one, are called though
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please confirm if $killrow is the correct row you want to delete? Console.log($killrow) and check if its the same. Also check if "success" class have be added. It will also be great if you can provide a snippet.

Comment: Hm. Logging it out shows [object Object] and $killrow.className is undefined

Comment: what is Console.log($killrow[0])?

Comment: undefined. It should be [object HTMLTableRowElement]

Comment: That is the issue. Please fix that.

Comment: Somehow when I place `var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');` outside the big if, so it is written only once in the code, it runs beautifully. Any ideas, why?

Comment: Can you please share bit more code? Looks like interesting thing.